# Looking for material to self-study uniform integrability of sequences of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I need some book recommendation on uniform integrability of sequences of random variables, preferably something that also covers relation between that notion and the different modes of convergences of sequences of random variables.

thanks !

Comment: K L Chung's book is a good reference.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, he's got many though, which one is it ? Introduction to stochastic integration ?

Comment: Section 4.5 of 'A Course in Probability Theory'.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiPp-OR2PTfAhVimeAKHYkRB4UQFjAAegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FJorge_Hernandez_Hernandez%2Fpost%2FUniform_integrability%2Fattachment%2F59d655a979197b80779acc16%2FAS%253A526603123343360%25401502563376253%2Fdownload%2Funiform%2Bintegrability.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2YhMllD3KF9T64OQrsq4ee) may be of interest.